# How to remove local merged branches

Tags: git

I'm following [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow/) to work with git. After days of work, there are always a lot of local branches in local. Much of them are useless as they are already merged into upstream.

So I need to remove these unused branches in period, the solution I use currently is

1. Filter merged branch with `git branch --merged`
2. Then removed the list branches at once.

This solution is a little messy, is there a easier way to clean them up?